# On the expression of the Galois conjugates in terms of the coordinates in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field and let $L$ be a Galois extension of $K$. Assume that $[L:K]=n$, and consider $e=(e_1, e_2, ...,e_n)$ a basis of $L$ over $K$. We note $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)=\left\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,..., \sigma_n \right\}$.

Can we find a matrix $P(e)\in \operatorname{Gl}_n(L)$ (that depends on $e$) such that for all $x\in L$, say $x=x_1 e_1+ x_2e_2 +...+x_n e_n$ (where $x_i\in K$ for $i\in \left\{1,2,...,n \right\}$), one has
$$ (\sigma_1(x), \sigma_2(x), ..., \sigma_n(x))=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \cdot P(e) \quad \text{?}$$
Is this matrix easily calculable ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you put $x=e_i$, you see that

$$(\sigma_1(e_i), \dots, \sigma_n(e_i)) = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0) P(e)$$

$$= \text{$i^{th}$ row of } P(e)$$

where the $1$ in $(0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)$ is in the $i$th place. Thus the only possible candidate for $P(e)$ is the matrix whose $i$th row is $(\sigma_1(e_i), \dots, \sigma_n(e_i))$. Then if $x = \sum x_i e_i$ is arbitrary,

$$(\sigma_1(x), \dots, \sigma_n(x)) = (\sum x_i \sigma_1(e_i), \dots, \sum x_i \sigma_n(e_i)) = (x_1, \dots, x_n) P(e),$$

so $P(e)$ is the matrix you are looking for.

Comment: Of course ! Many thanks !

Comment: @Stabilo My pleasure